# Linux "which virtualenv-2.7" shows a repeating path

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, virtualenv, certbot

I think I messed up some components when trying to install ruby, and not `virtualenv-2.7` seems to be broken.

I am not even sure if I am describing the problem correctly, as I can't figure out the issue, let alone a solution to it.  It's not in `bash_profile` (my only real lead based on my limited understanding).  I don't know where else to even look or what to search for.

Running which `virtualenv-2.7` results in:

```
$ which virtualenv-2.7
/usr/bin/which: no virtualenv-2.7 in (/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-use ... nv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)
```

ending in

> ... :/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)

I discovered this trying to install `certbot`

> $ sudo ./certbot-auto --debug renew
>   Package python27-pip-6.1.1-1.23.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
>   Nothing to do
>   Creating virtual environment...
>   **./certbot-auto: line 864: virtualenv: command not found**

How do I fix this?  Will just uninstalling `viartualenv-2.7` and re-installing it help, and how?